# How do you set the smaller grid mode by default?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, there are two modes for looking at items in the shop. A descriptive mode that tells you information about each item, and a more minimal mode that just shows the items.

I have no problem switching between the two, but I can't set the minimal mode as the default mode. Every time I start the game, it always sets the larger list mode.

It didn't used to do this, however. It only changed after I altered the setting in the file game.cfg. I repaired the client and changed the game.cfg to its original settings, but it still hasn't fixed the problem.

Short of just installing the game again, does anyone know hot to make the minimal mode as the default setting?

Comment: Once I changed it, it never went back... playing with game files isn't the greatest idea without a back up of the originals.

Comment: That's for sure, haha. I'm honestly probably just going to fresh install it, but I wanted to check if there was any other way to change it.

Comment: You could ask for a friend (or forum member) to upload their (untouched) game.cfg and use that file yourself.

Comment: Huh...That way I can make sure I've covered all my bases. I'll try it.

Comment: It worked @MarcoGeertsma! I'm guessing that since it was a .cfg file and not just a .txt file, there were probably some changes I made that I couldn't see. Do you want to list your answer as the answer so you can get credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask for a friend (or forum member) to upload their (untouched) game.cfg and use that file yourself.

Comment: The only word of caution I will say is that it'll change your settings, so your game might have a different resolution, sound, etc, compared to what you're used to, but that can be easily adjusted.

Comment: True, since you basically set your game file to default installation state, all the settings you changed regarding that file will be lost.